# Add translation to Eclipse e4 PartStack in RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, localization, e4

I'm trying to translate the context menu entries in our e4 RCP application, such as "Close" and "Close All" in the PartStacks context menu.

Since I saw the Babel Plugin doing exactly that for the Eclipse IDE, I checked out their code and how they were doing it. It seems that they added a plugin

> org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench.nl_de

which contains a "message_de.properties" under the same folder/package structure as the default "message.properties", namely "org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt".

Well, I tried that in our own application but - as I expected - it didn't work. What am I missing? I guess I'm missing some important points here, as the whole logic of having messages.properties files, rather than hard coded strings is to allow for localization, right?

Comment: How are the context menu items defined? Is this in the Application.e4xmi or in your code? If it is in code are you using the message.properties already?

Comment: @greg-449 They are programmatically added in the class StackRenderer which is a e4 framework class. In turn, StackRenderer uses the NLS class SWTRenderersMessages to get the item labels. I want to implement our own renderer extending StackRenderer. But I don't want to touch the default behavior, and rather only change the labels.

Comment: SWTRenderersMessages will look for messages_de.properties but only in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt` folder in the plugin or a plugin fragment. So you should be able to make this work using a plugin fragment.

Comment: @greg-449 Great! Thank you. I was totally missing the fragment concept here. Now it all makes sense and works neatly. Do you mind posting an acceptable answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add extra message properties files you should use a 'plugin fragment' which extends the plugin. This is what the Babel jars use.

Use 'File > New > Project > Plug-in Development > Fragment Project' to create a plugin fragment project.

In this particular case `SWTRenderersMessages` will look for `messages_de.properties` but only in the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt` folder in the plugin or a plugin fragment.